# Are there any latex house paints that aren't 100% acrylic anymore?

Tags: painting, repainting

Although I've heard of latex paints that use a mix of other binders (eg. styrene acrylic or vinyl acrylic), and therefore aren't 100% acrylic, I've never seen them in real life.

Are we pretty much at the point such that 99.9% of latex paints you see in a hardware store are "100% Acrylic," or should we still be paying attention to the percentage of acrylic binders in a latex paint?

Comment: https://www.perfectpainter.ca/painting-companies-toronto/selecting-acrylic-latex-paint/

Comment: @AlaskaMan thanks for sharing the link. However, that article might not be written by the best authority on paint though. They have a few unique beliefs such as: 1) they believe that acrylic paint is mostly for art projects and not houses (it's hard to find house paint that's NOT acrylic in Walmart), 2) Acrylic paint can be high in fumes (many are actually zero VOC), 3) Acrylic requires chemical thinners to clean (acrylic can be cleaned with water/soap).  Don't shoot the messenger here - I'm just noting that they have claims that I personally haven't seen anywhere else.

Comment: They may be confusing water based acrylic with acrylic lacquer, I have also used acrylic that had white spirit as the solvent,  acrylic is a very versitile type of resin...